# Map creation with string**. I guess I'm on the wrong way

Tags: c++, string

I'm coming to you because I'm beginner in C++, was programming in C, and I'm a bit lost when I have to create a map.

In fact, I'm used to manipulate char** when I want to create a map from program parameters.
That is the kind of map I wanna create :

```
*******
*     *
*     *
*******
```

If it was in C, I would have done:
char **map;

```
map = malloc(sizeof(char*) * sizeY);
while (i < sizeY)
{
  map[i] = malloc(sizeof(char**) * sizeX);
  ++i;
}
```

But, I'm in c++ and I'm trying to use string.
And here is the problem, I can't manipulate it on the same way as a char**.

The only thing I'm able to compile is :

```
  _map = new std::string*;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i)
  {
    _map[i] = new std::string[sizeY * sizeX];
  }
```

but, of course, that don't work properly when I'm trying to make full the map.

Can someone help me or guide me to something ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You don't need the pointers. You certainly don't need the pointers to pointers. What you need to do is spend some time learning C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the standard library provides classes to manage dynamic arrays for us:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> map(sizeY, std::string(sizeX, ' '));
```

If you wanted an exercise in juggling pointers, then you'd want something more like

```
std::string * map = new std::string[sizeY];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i) {
    map[i].resize(sizeX);
}

// don't forget to delete it when you've finished
delete [] map;
```

When you learn about the concept of *exception safety*, you'll understand why this is a bad idea; you should always use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) classes like `std::vector` to manage dynamic resources.

Comment: Yea I will go for it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
vector <string> map;    
cin>>size;    
map.resize(size);
```

See [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

On a side note, in C it would be

```
map[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeX);
```

not

```
map[i] = malloc(sizeof(char**) * sizeX);
```

Comment: I know about vector, map with charkey and cie. But I heard that it is not really optimize.
But your solutions seem to be very smart, fast and easy.

I will go for it :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a jagged array. Instead store your map in continuous memory using for example an `std::vector`. You can write a class to keep all your map related code in one place.

```
class Map
{
    Map(int rows, int cols)
    : rows_(rows), cols_(cols), cells_(rows*cols,' ') {}

    char& operator()(int r, int c) {
        return cells_[index(r,c)];
    }

    size_t index(int r, int c) const {
        return r*cols_ + c;
    }

private:
    int rows_, cols_;
    vector<char> cells_;
};
```

Usage:

```
Map map(4,7);
map(0,0) = '*';
```

Comment: That is a good idea, I won't use it in my small projet (create a snake game) but I keep it in mind for the next project.